# Binary files gets corrupted when transferred over a socket

Tags: c, sockets

Hi While creating a simple ftp program using socket programming I am having following issues.

Brief introduction about my application

server end: which reads file requested by client and then write it on client socket.

client end: this reads the data send by client and saves to disk.

When I am transferring normal text file from my server I am getting correct file in client. But when I am transferring some other files like pdfs or executables then when I compared both files they have same sizes but the file saved by my client to disk is corrupted.

For example If my server wrote 4000 bytes binary file to client socket. Then when my client is saving it to disk then the size is same 4000 bytes. But when I gave it executable permissions using chmod and try to execute it then I am getting error like: cannot execute binary file.

Similarly when I am transferring pdf files and when I double click to open nothing shows up.

In client side also I have checked whether the read call is reading whole data or not and it is reading the whole data from the socket.

Is this something to do with serialization. My client and server are both running on the same system only compiled with same compiler.

My program is quite big with many error checks so I am pasting a little modified code here which explains the issue For simplicity i have used many static things too:

**server.c**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
// validate proper usage
if (argc != 4)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage %s <serverBindIP> <serverBindPort> <CredentialsFilePath>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(-1);
}

// create signal hanlder's
// TODO

// store the command line arguments supplied
char* ip = argv[1];
int port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));
char* passwd_file = argv[3];
struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;

int server_fd, client_fd, result;
socklen_t length;

// Create an internet domain TCP socket
server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (server_fd == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to create socket\n");
    exit(-1);
}

server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_port = port;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip);

// bind socket to an network interface
result = bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
if (result == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to bind socket\n");
    exit(-1);
}

// mark the socket used for incoming requests
listen(server_fd, 5);

// accept an incoming connection
printf("Waiting for incoming connection\n");
length = sizeof(client_addr);
client_fd = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*) &client_addr, &length);
if (client_fd == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to accept peer connection\n");
    exit(-1);
}

// read and send one full file
struct stat stats;
stat("/home/xpansat/book.pdf", &stats);
int size = stats.st_size;

// send size of file to the client
write(client_fd, &size, sizeof(int));

FILE* in = fopen("/home/xpansat/book.pdf", "rb");
char *buffer = malloc(size);
fread(buffer, 1, size, in);

write(client_fd, buffer, size);

fclose(in);
```

return 0;
}

**client.c**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
// validate proper usage
if (argc != 3)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <serverIP> <serverPort>\n", argv[0]);
    exit(-1);
}

// store the command line arguments 
char *server_ip = argv[1];
int server_port = htons(atoi(argv[2]));

// stores address of remote server to connect
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
int fd, option;

fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (fd == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error creating socket\n");
    exit(-1);
}

memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));

server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_ip);
server_addr.sin_port = server_port;

if (connect(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Error connecting to server\n");
    exit(-1);
}
int size = 0;

// read file size first
read(fd, &size, sizeof(int));

int bytes_read = 0;
int to_read = size;
FILE* out = fopen("book2.pdf", "wb");

char *buffer = malloc(size);
do
{
    bytes_read = read(fd, buffer, to_read);
    printf("To read: %d\n", to_read);
    printf("Data read: %d\n", bytes_read);
    to_read = to_read - bytes_read;

    // save content to disk
    fwrite(buffer, 1, bytes_read, out);
} while (to_read != 0);


return 0;
}
```

Though I have got good suggestions for this code, but what I got to know this code pasted here by me doesn't actually specify my problem, as I found out that while filling the buffer to send to client I was copying data into it using strncpy function, which makes executables corrupt some how (maybe beacuse that extra \0 it puts into the end but I am not sure why). So the thing which actually resolved my problem was: replacing all strncpy function with memcpy function and now I am able to transfer binary files properly too. So, this solves my problem.

Comment: I checked that too its reading the whole data made code change for that too above

Comment: Well, when transferring files, it's kinda normal for the server to indicate when the whole file has been sent, (eg. by closing the socket so that the client read retruns with 0, or using some hiher-level protocol).  Gettting some file size at the client is, to say the least, borken.

Comment: Hi thanks its working now with the above code change I did. But still in my actual program its not working might be some other wrong logic. Actually in my actual program I am reading similarly but from server I am sending data in 4096 bytes chunks. Anyway one thing I wanted to clear that is there any special method for binary file transfer and from this I assume that the binary files also get transferred the same way.

Comment: It's usually wise to be more explicit about the endian-ness of the data when you're coding like this. If the client and the server don't agree, you'll get some nasty results.

Comment: How to close this post now?. As I got to knnow I was dumb.

Comment: Nah - you should leave your dumbness around for all to laugh at :)

Comment: both client and server should close() the socket when done

Comment: accept() return code check: 'if (client_fd == -1)' should be: 'if (client_fd < 0)'

Comment: I would strongly suggest using 'send()' to send the message/file to the client rather than using 'write()'

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments. One more thing I want to share my actual application also started working perfectly fine. Earlier after reading from the binary file in server.c I was copying that data to buffer using strncpy, I changed that to memcpy instead and everything started to working fine.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using 'recv()' to get the message/file from the server rather than using 'read()'

Comment: This line: 'bytes_read = read(fd, buffer, to_read);'  is using the read() function, which blocks (because the socket has not been set to non-blocking) until the requested number of bytes is read, so the surrounding for loop will only be performed once.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

note: for fread and fwrite, the order of the parameters is: 
&buffer, sizeOfElement, number of elements, fileDescriptor
for the posted code, the indication is each element is 1 byte long
and there are 'fileSize' number of elements

(Usually) tcp/ip does not deliver packets larger than ~1600 bytes.
so, normally, that is all the faster the data should be sent.

The normal method is to use select() and read() in a loop, until the timeout on select() expires,  Where the passed block number and the block length field from the first packet indicate where in the input buffer to place the next read data block.

remember to always re-set the timeout variable before each call to select().

This size limitation on the data block size in TCP/IP indicates the data should be written a reasonable block size at a time, say 1024 data bytes per call to write()

When setting up the select/read loop, the read socket should be set to non-blocking, (especially) as the final block (probably) will not be a full read block in length.
the client should be checking the number of bytes read, after each read() to assure a full block was received.

It is a good idea to sent an initial block that contains the file name, the actual number of bytes to be transferred, the check-sum for the whole file, and the data block size.

Each packet should have a header that indicates the block number and number of data bytes in the packet.

(with -1 for the initial block that contains the file name and total file size, and 'this' packet size)

dont close the write socket without first getting some indication from the client that the file was transferred correctly.

to assure that all the data has been read by the client,
have the client send a 'ack' packet  after receiving each data block.
suggest the ack packet include the block number from the received packet.

Then, after the server has received the last ack packet, then the server can close the socket.  If the server receives a nak packet, it means the file transfer needs to be done again.

```
the client should be doing these things,
1) waiting for the select() to timeout,
2) assuring that all blocks were received
3) assuring the file checksum matches the passed checksum from data block 0
4) sending a ack for each packet received
5) sending a final ack if the checksum matches, else send a nak
```

Note:
although it is slower, I like to set the select()/read() loop to only read a single byte at at time,  This will mean a lot more iterations of the loop, but makes setting the read socket to non-blocking a much safer method.

the above may seem a lot more complex that a single write and a single read, but it will eliminate un-noticed communication errors and un-noticed corrupt data

Comment: for fread rahther than doing this:

fread(buffer, 1, size, in);

should I do this:
fread(buffer, size, 1, in);

Comment: there's no requrement to use non-blocking reads, read on sockets will return as soon as there is data available (so unfilled read buffers won't cause delays or hangs)

Comment: my experience, embedded ubuntu linux, is that the read will block until the input count is fulfilled.  That is why I suggested a select/read loop and only read 1 char on each itteration of the loop and exiting the loop on a timeout

Comment: @mSatyam: No, don't do that; what you have is better. The performance will be the same (because any sane implementation - eg glibc - will convert both to a read() on size*nmemb iteems), but with `1, size` `fread` will return the number of bytes read, whereas with `size,1` it will return 0 unless the whole data was read in one go.

Comment: @user3629249: "(Usually) tcp/ip does not deliver packets larger than ~1600 bytes. so, normally, that is all the faster the data should be sent." No, that's wrong. Just because the protocol may split things up into packets doesn't imply you should try to as well. Performance will be determined by many things, so it's important to measure, but as a general rule of thumb it's best to minimise the number of system calls (eg `read()`/`write()`); if you have all the data available it's often best to send it all in one go: fewer syscalls & the kernel can make more intelligent choices about packets.

Comment: @user3629249: The timeout in `select()` is for the case where the other side stops sending data unexpectedly. In the normal file transfer case where the other side sends all its data rapidly, the timeout should not get hit.

Comment: @user3629249: Also note that TCP has no concept of a "block": there is no guarantee that separate `write()` calls on one end will be received as separate `read()` calls on the other: separate writes can be amalgamated into one, and/or individual writes can be split up over separate reads. So if you want to use blocks in your protocol, you have to (eg) add a header to the start of each block with its length, so that the receiver can tell where each block starts & ends. If you're always sending whole files, it may be just as simple to send the file length at the start, and not use blocks at all.

Comment: @user3629249: "Note: although it is slower, I like to set the select()/read() loop to only read a single byte at at time," This is not necessary at all for avoiding errors, and will generally *kill* performance.

Comment: Both `read()` and `write()` have return values that are either an error code, or the number of bytes transferred. There is no guarantee that the size requested is actually transfered, so the pattern used in the client to read the data from the socket needs to be applied to writes in the server too.  The same applies to `fread()` and `fwrite()`.

Comment: @marko: not quite - for `fread()` and `fwrite()` the value returned is the number of *items* read/written. So if you request 1000 items of size 1 byte, then yes, you get back the number of bytes - but if you request 1 item of 1000 bytes, then unless the read completed fully, the value you get back will not tell you how many bytes were read from the socket.

Comment: What @psmears said.  Attempting to make 'optimizations' at application-level because of some assumed restriction at L1, (eg. 'normal' ethernet MTU), will likely backfire and reduce performance.

Answer (score 0):

I made this change to the server and it suddenly started working.

```
// send size of file to the client
write(client_fd, &size, sizeof(int));
```

I alsoi added some #includes to the top

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>          /* See NOTES */
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Comment: I did this change actually but forgot to update here. Anyway thanks a lot. For simplicity i didn't included #includes